# exec behaviour inside a class method

Tags: python-3.x

Why does `exec` fail to run this code, when it's called inside of a class method?

```
class test(object):
    def run(self):
        exec("f=lambda n:(n>15and f(n//16)or'')+'HBKD'[n//4%4]+'OAEI'[n%4];print(f(156))")

exec("g=lambda n:(n>15and g(n//16)or'')+'HBKD'[n//4%4]+'OAEI'[n%4];print(g(156))")
t = test()
t.run()
```

The `exec` call outside of the class works properly, but the call inside the `run()` function fails, and gives an `NameError`: 'NameError: name 'f' is not defined'. Why's that?

Comment: You can't set new local names with exec in a function, because locals are heavily optimised.

Comment: That's why if you execute it in `globals()` (or a custom namespace) with `exec("f=lambda n:(n>15and f(n//16)or'')+'HBKD'[n//4%4]+'OAEI'[n%4];print(f(156))", globals())` you're good to go.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I actually looked at that post for a while, but thought that I was in a different situation due to the class I have. Thanks!

Comment: @Jim Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @TuukkaX: you can trivially reproduce the same error without the class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yup. I just thought differently upon asking.